# Apply multiprocessing pool to function which takes multiple lists as argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have the following function:

```
def match_keywords(reviews_match, nlu_match, keywords_match):

    for j in range(df_NLU_Reviews.shape[0]):
        if((j%1000)==0):
            print(j)

        keywords = df_NLU_Reviews.Keywords.iloc[j]

        for i in range(len(sentences)):

            try:

                counter=0

                for keyword in keywords:
                    if(keyword in sentences[i]):
                        counter+=1

                if( (len(keywords)) == counter ):
                    reviews_match.append(sentences[i])
                    nlu_match.append(df_NLU_Reviews.NLU_Review.iloc[j])
                    keywords_match.append(df_NLU_Reviews.Keywords.iloc[j])
                    sentences.remove(sentences[i])
                    break
            except Exception as e:
                print(i)
                print(j)
                raise e

    df_match = pd.DataFrame()
    df_match['Reviews'] = reviews_match
    df_match['NLU'] = nlu_match
    df_match['Keywords'] = keywords_match
    df_match.to_pickle("Match_Reviews.pkl")

    return df_match
```

This function takes 3 empty lists as arguments that will be filled during the execution of the function.

I want to parallelize using `multiprocessing.Pool`, but i can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried this:

```
reviews_match = []
nlu_match = []
keywords_match = []

match_list = [reviews_match, nlu_match, keywords_match]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Pool(processes = 12) as pool:

        results = pool.map(match_keywords, zip(reviews_match, nlu_match, keywords_match))

    print(results)
```

this:

```
reviews_match = []
    nlu_match = []
    keywords_match = []

    match_list = [reviews_match, nlu_match, keywords_match]

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        with Pool(processes = 12) as pool:

            results = pool.map(match_keywords, zip(match_list))

        print(results)
```

and this too:

```
reviews_match = []
    nlu_match = []
    keywords_match = []

    match_list = [reviews_match, nlu_match, keywords_match]

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        with Pool(processes = 12) as pool:

            results = pool.starmap(match_keywords, zip(reviews_match, nlu_match, keywords_match))

        print(results)
```

But none of this works, these methods throw errors or empty lists as output. If i run this function without parallelization like this:

`match_keywords(reviews_match, nlu_match, keywords_match)`

It works just fine. Could someone please show me the right way of doing this and explain to me why this is not working?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: For one thing: you are passing 1 argument in `map()` (the zip iterator), while the function `match_keywords` expects 3 arguments.

Comment: I know, i was just trying my chances because nothing works, i didn't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

You last variant look correct and will not return empty list, check it again.

But i think you can't parallelise it this way, because it is not equal to run

`match_keywords(reviews_match, nlu_match, keywords_match)`

in many threads, it is equal to run:

```
match_keywords(reviews_match[0], nlu_match[0], keywords_match[0])
match_keywords(reviews_match[1], nlu_match[1], keywords_match[1])
match_keywords(reviews_match[2], nlu_match[2], keywords_match[2])
match_keywords(reviews_match[3], nlu_match[3], keywords_match[3])
...
```

many times.

Comment: Thank you LinnTroll. In fact the last variant also returns an empty list, i checked it again. If i can't parallelize it this way, do you know if there is any other way you could suggest me please?